# How do I create row and column dependent color coding using csvsimple?

Tags: color, csvsimple, cell

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
freq   ,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,C
100\,Hz, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,10\,nF
200\,Hz,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,10\,nF
300\,Hz,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,20\,nF
400\,Hz,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,20\,nF
500\,Hz,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,30\,nF
600\,Hz,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,30\,nF
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\definecolor{tch}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{tc1l}{gray}{0.90}
\definecolor{tc2l}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{tc1d}{gray}{0.80}
\definecolor{tc2d}{gray}{0.85}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2.5pt}

\csvreader[
  longtable=>{\raggedleft}p{4.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft}p{2.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
            >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}%
                          p{3.0em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt},
  table head=\arrayrulecolor{white}\hline\rowcolor{tch}
    {\color{white}\bf Frequency} &
    {\color{white}\bf R1} &
    {\color{white}\bf R2} &
    {\color{white}\bf R3} &
    {\color{white}\bf R4} &
    {\color{white}\bf R5} &
    {\color{white}\bf R6} &
    {\color{white}\bf R7} &
    {\color{white}\bf R8} &
    {\color{white}\bf R9} &
    {\color{white}\bf Cap},
    late after head=\\\endhead\rowcolor{tc1l},
    late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\hline\rowcolor{tc1l}}
                                {\\\hline\rowcolor{tc2l}},
]
{test.csv}
{freq=\freq,R1=\ra,R2=\rb,R3=\rc,R4=\rd,R5=\re,R6=\rf,R7=\rg,R8=\rh,
            R9=\ri,C=\c}
{\freq & \ra & \rb & \rc & \rd & \re & \rf & \rg & \rh & \ri & \c}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:

[image: nice, but blurry result]

However, I need something like shown in the following picture. I don't know how to create it based on the cell's row and column number. How would I best go about this (hoping to be able to do this with csvsimple)?

[image]

Comment: Use `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: No way to continue to use csvsimple? I've just gotten familiar with csvsimple and now I should look into yet another package?

Comment: There might be (probably something with tikzmarks or something similar), but the simple in the name of csvsimple is not that wrong. You could maybe try to manually insert a kind of color/cellcolor macro at the start of each cell which only adjusts in the row and column you want it to, but it it probably is a very large effort.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll look into `pgfplotstable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited this answer in light of TeXnician's comment. Previously I did not have an answer, just a suggestion. In order to show that the suggestion actually accomplishes the desired result, here is the code using the `datatool` package. Maybe something like this can be done with `csvsimple`, but as TeXnician rightly points out, the 'simple' in `csvsimple` makes me suspect that it cannot.

Note: in the code that follows, `test.csv` is the same as in the example above except that the cells with a `\,` in them are in quotation marks so that they can be read as part of a `csv` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\definecolor{lgray}{gray}{0.7}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2.5pt}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{data}{test.csv}

\begin{tabular}{*{11}{|r}}
\rowcolor{gray}
\dtlforeachkey(\theKey,\theCol,\theType,\theHead)\in{data}\do
 {\ifthenelse{\equal{\theCol}{1}}{}{&}{\color{white}\bf\theHead}} \\\hline%
\DTLforeach*{data}{}
{%
\gdef\rowint{20}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theDTLrowi}{1}}{\gdef\rowint{40}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theDTLrowi}{3}}{\gdef\rowint{70}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\theDTLrowi}{5}}{\gdef\rowint{40}}{}
\DTLforeachkeyinrow{\v}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\dtlcol}{1}}{}{&}%
\cellcolor{lgray!\rowint}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\dtlcol}{1}}{\cellcolor{blue!\rowint}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\dtlcol}{5}}{\cellcolor{gray!\rowint}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\dtlcol}{6}}{\cellcolor{gray!\rowint}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\dtlcol}{7}}{\cellcolor{gray!\rowint}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\dtlcol}{11}}{\cellcolor{green!\rowint}}{}%
\v}%
\\\hline
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a good idea, but has one drawback: The differing colors. You use cellcolor once, but this highlighted row has four different color intensities.

Comment: Wow this is really cool. it works like a charm. It doesn't really matter to me how to do this, I don't need to use `csvsimple`. I just dreaded the coding so I highly appreciate the time you've taken to do so.